# Electromagnetic mass of a continuous charge distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I am trying to understand if it is possible to have a consistent solution to Maxwell's equations and Lorentz force equation simultaneously with no other forces present. The Lorentz force density is $f^a = {F^a}_b j^b$, where ${F_a}_b$ is the electromagnetic tensor.

a) How to write the equation of motion? I want to write something like $v^{a}\nabla_a (mv^b) = f^b$, where $m$ is electromagnetic mass density and $v^{a} = j^{a}/ \rho$ is 4-velocity of the charge distribution, $m$ and $\rho$ are proper. Does this equation make sense?

b) How to calculate electromagnetic charge density?

c) I pose the following initial conditions problem. Fix a reference frame so that $t=0$ is defined, define $j^a$ for $t=0$. I want to obtain ${F_a}_b$, $j^a$ for the whole of $R^4$ satisfying Maxwell's equations and the Lorentz force equation. Is there solutions? I understand that solutions (if there are any) will not be very interesting because without other forces concentrated particles will disperse, but maybe someone can help me satisfy my curiosity. Thank you.

Edit: I partially answered the question myself. There is no need to add electromagnetic mass in the equation of motion because it's been already accounted for by the action of the field on the charge distribution which in turn produces the field.

Therefore, there is no need to calculate electromagnetic mass to pose the question (c), but we need some rest mass for equation $v^{a}\nabla_a (mv^b) = f^b$ to make sense. I guess to get solutions for massless charge distribution, we can solve it for some $m$ and then take the limit as $m \to 0$, hoping that solutions will converge. I think they should because the standard examples in textbooks show that (apparent) electromagnetic mass **adds** to rest mass in equations of motion.

Comment: Are you asking a mathematical or a physical question? The answer to the physical question is "No, it is not possible to have a consistent solution to an exclusively classical EM universe". It's not required , either, electromagnetism was never a candidate for a TOE. It describes a wide variety of physical phenomena very well and completely fails phenomenologically on an even wider variety. Classical EM can't even tell you anything about the microscopic physics of charge distributions. It simply postulates that they exist and then predicts how they behave in a certain limit.

Comment: Here on the StackExchange network, we prefer one question per post--sometimes a second question can be squeezed in if necessary. Here, you have around 10 questions, which is far too many. Could you reduce the number of questions to a more suitable number (one or two closely related questions), thereby making this less broad?

Comment: CuriousOne, I understand that it is not possible to have consistent solutions in EM universe if we want point charges or model a point charge by a concentrated volume of charge density. But if we don't require that can it be consistent?

Comment: Kyle Kanos, I removed the unrelated question.

Comment: @bors: The answer to your question probably depends on your notion of consistence. A charge distribution in free space is, all by itself, always unstable. A distribution with a net charge will always diverge towards infinity (as you said), and one without net charge will collapse, with electromagnetic waves carrying away angular momentum and energy. Independent of the details of the math, I would assume that how it does that would be described mostly correctly by classical electromagnetism, at least for the case of macroscopic distributions.